# Debezium database schema history vs schema.history property

Tags: debezium

i'm new to debezium and  i cannot understand what is stored in the topic created from schema.history property vs the one for database schema history. I understand that both stores DDl changes but cannot see what is the difference between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One if for internal use , the one starting with __history, and the other is meant to be used for clients